# How Microsoft Access can download a file from webserver

Tags: ms-access

I am a web developer and  have no idea how Microsoft Access works. I have received a new request from my boss

We have people on field who do surveys and uses access database for that.

They  download a .zip file from the company website to pre fill their surveys.

They have to  follow these steps.
1. Log in to company  website 
2. locate and download the .zip file 
3. Copy the file from download location and paste it in a predefined location 
4. Activate the automated process to read file from the specified location and  populate the database.

I have been asked to simplify this process where field people can skip logging to the website  to download the file  and do it directly from access? Is this possible ?

FYI : To connect to web server we use a secure SSH connection.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  I've done this in the past but can't recall exactly how, which is why I'm not posting it as an answer.  I'll see if I can find the code but I have a feeling it's gone.

Answer (score -1):

You can have all of this happen in the background by using Application.SendKeys.  Take a look at the [MS doc](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/HV080207362.aspx) to see how it's used to open the calculator and input some numbers.  Use the same idea and log into the website by sending the appropriate info using SendKeys.  I think when I did this I read the user's login info from the registry so that it didn't need to be hard-coded.

Comment: Thanks for  pointing me to  right direction.I'll give it a try and see how far I can go..